# MassEdits on referenceEdits

Tags: python, maya

I've got issues with the maya function `referenceEdit`.

For my job I've to clean animators scenes for our client in order to be sure there is no animations on meshes, no mesh hided, etc...

So I would like to delete referenceEdits on all my meshes when an animator validated his shot. But if I make a for loop on meshes for delete their referenceEdits if they've any, Maya takes much more time than expected even in batchMode I could jump on something like 30-90 min per scene just for this step of cleaning.

I tried to make it with threading but Maya seems to not like it, here is my code without threading:

```
import time
start = time.time()
debug=False

meshes = cmds.ls( type='mesh', ap=True, recursive=True )
tr_meshes = [ cmds.listRelatives( x, p=True, path=True)[0] for x in meshes ]
to_test = list( set( meshes+tr_meshes ) )

edit_types = ['addAttr', 'connectAttr', 'deleteAttr', 'disconnectAttr', 'parent', 'setAttr', 'lock', 'unlock']

if to_test:
    for x in to_test:
        if debug: print '.',x
        for edit_type in edit_types:
            edits = cmds.referenceQuery( x, editStrings=True, editCommand=edit_type, successfulEdits=True, failedEdits=True )
            if edits:
                # Then Delete ReferenceEdits on it
                cmds.referenceEdit( x, removeEdits=True, editCommand=edit_type, successfulEdits=True, failedEdits=True )
                if debug: 
                    for y in edits:
                        print '\t.',y

print time.time() - start
```

Anybody knows how to achieve this faster please? Like something in Maya API? Or something else?

My other trail is by editing directly the .ma but it's quite dangerous isn't it?

[EDIT] I forgot to say I open my scenes without loading refs, launch my script and then save it and reopen it for other operations of cleaning just for be sure nothing brokes during the step

Comment: Your English is fine, even relative to some native speakers.

Comment: when I was dealing with ref edit, I was unloading the ref I wanted to clean. Most of the time without this precaution, I may end into a crash

Comment: Thanks Drise
Yes I forgot to say I open scenes whitout loading refs before launch my script and then I save my scene and reOpen it. But it's still long to execute